# Find the variance of point estimator $X$ where $X = aX_1 + (1-a)X_2$ and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are samples from a pop of avg = $\mu$ and var=$\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the averages of two random samples of sizes
>   $n_1$ and $n_2$, respectively, extracted from a normal population of average
>   $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
>
> a) Show that
>
> $$X = aX_1+(1-a)X_2, 0<a<1$$
>
> is an ubiased estimator of $\mu$.
>
> b) Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Determine the
>   variance of estimator X and the value of a that minimizes that
>   variance.

My professor solved it this way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why did he use the population mean in the a) but used the sample variance in b) instead of the given one?

Comment: This is still the population variance. It's just the population variance of a population of sample means.$$\overline{X_i}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n_i)\quad\text{for }i=1,2$$

Comment: @PeterForeman I get that but what about the variances of X_1 and X_2? Why didn't he use just $\sigma^2$?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. The variance of $\overline{X_1}$ is $\sigma^2/n_1$ it's not $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Why not type out the material instead of attaching pictures?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the moments of the sampling distribution with estimators of the parameters of a distribution.

Let us define some terms:

- $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ is a **sample** drawn from some common distribution $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  So in particular, each $X_i$ is independent and identically distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
- The **sample mean** is $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$ and as a function of the random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, it is a **statistic**.  It is also an **estimator** because it estimates the true mean $\mu$.
- Since $\bar X$ is itself a random variable that is a function of other random variables, it has its own distribution, called the **sampling distribution**.  If the $X_i$ are normally distributed, then $$\bar X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2/n);$$ that is to say, the sample mean is also normally distributed with mean $\mu$, but its variance is not $\sigma^2$--instead, it is $\sigma^2/n$.
- The **sample variance** is the statistic $$s_X^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2.$$  This is not employed in this question and is not relevant to the question.  It is an estimator for the parameter $\sigma^2$.  But you are not asked about this statistic.  You are asked about the statistic $\bar X$ only; in particular, about the mean and variance of the sampling distribution of a weighted average of two sample means drawn from the same population.